# Which is the more common reading of 仏陀 - ぶつだ or ブッダ?

Tags: pronunciation, readings

I realize that 仏陀 is probably more common in writing where the reading is ambiguous anyway, but I am curious to know: do people tend to read it as ぶつだ or ブッダ? For what it's worth, my IME recognizes both, and the one time I did hear it in speech it was ブッダ.

Comment: There was a Japanese service for this very question posted here recently, but according to Kanshudo, https://www.kanshudo.com/searchq?q=仏陀 , “The most common reading is ぶっだ (used about 90% of the time)“.

Comment: (Excuse my ignorance) I didn't even know 仏陀 could be read ぶ**つ**だ... (> <)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aeon.

Before you learn which is better, you have to know that *furigara* is not the same as pronunciation. Certainly *furigana* shows us how to read its *kanji*, but we sometimes don't write small *hiragana* or *katakana* because we didn't have such sounds before Kamakura Period. *Hiragana* and *katakana* are not so precise phonograms.

The answer is Buddha, ブッダ. I've never seen the form, ぶつだ, but it may be a sort of old way to write or miswritten.

Furthermore, most of people do not call him Buddha, but *Hotoke(sama)* or *Oshaka(sama)* instead. *Sama* is a suffix like title which used to call someone else out of respect.

Comment: I actually asked mainly because I'd seen the ぶつだ reading in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

[https://furigana.info/w/仏陀](https://furigana.info/w/%E4%BB%8F%E9%99%80) (based on old fiction):
60% of ぶっだ >< 30% of ぶつだ (plus weird people who want to spell ほとけ thus and similar).

kanshudo.com/searchq?q=仏陀 (based on modern use):
90% ぶっだ >< 10% ぶつだ.

Thus, it at least seems that ぶっだ is the more popular reading, and ぶつだ actually loses prominence.